# Ruby example with exclamation mark

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments

I am writing a script with different options in ruby, and I can't understand how the OptionParser could help me.

In particular, there is an example in the documentation: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!

p options
p ARGV
```

I can understand the exclamation mark on the "end.parse" line (but I expected a parameter after that), but I find the following 2 lines confusing, `p` hasn't been declared, and I can't understand if it's part of the example source.

And how do I use the '-v' option? Do I simply check if options[:v] is `nil` or `true`?

Last thing, what happens to the other options? Does the OptionParser only parse switches? What if I had other parameters after the '-v'? Like `myscript -v duck ketchup banana`?

Comment: `p` is [defined in `Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p), so it is (almost) always available in Ruby. `p obj` is equivalent to `puts obj.inspect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> I can understand the exclamation mark on the "end.parse" line (but I expected a parameter after that)

[The documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html#method-i-parse-21) states that `parse!` takes an optional `argv` parameter. If it is not supplied, it defaults to `default_argv`, which I imagine is the string containing the arguments passed to this script in the command line.

> p hasn't been declared, and I can't understand if it's part of the example source

`p` is [defined in `Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p), so it is (almost) always available in Ruby. `p obj` is equivalent to `puts obj.inspect`.

In this context, `p` is just used to illustrate that after parsing the arguments, the `options` hash contains all the flags/options you defined in the OptionParser block.

> And how do I use the '-v' option? Do I simply check if options[:v] is nil or true?

Yes, but that would actually be `options[:verbose]`.

> Last thing, what happens to the other options? Does the OptionParser only parse switches? What if I had other parameters after the '-v'? Like `myscript -v duck ketchup banana`?

You will have to make multiple calls to `opts.on` to match all the other switches/arguments you are interested in. Look at the documentation [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch) for explanations on how to do that.

Comment: To be precise, `p` is available in instances of all classes, explicitly including `Kernel` and/or derived from `Object`, including `main`. It is _not defined_ in instances of classes, derived directly from `BasicObject` and not including `Kernel` (usually this happens to DSL.) BTW, upvoted for great formatting.